# Javascript/jQuery ajax Select not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following jquery code, in which I'm trying to get some data using ajax and then populating a select which I placed in the body of my html document:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurlhere',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
        });
    }
});
```

Result from the ajax call gets this data:

```
{
   "651":{
      "name":"somename",
      "stts":{
         "opt1":2,
         "opt2":1,
         "opt3":"0"
      }
   },
   "659":{
      "name":"someothername",
      "stts":{
         "opt1":2,
         "opt2":1,
         "opt3":"0"
      }
   }

}
```

And this is the html:

```
<select id="#myselect"></select>
```

I can see that the data is collected but it's not populating the SELECT.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<select id="#myselect"></select>` should be `<select id="myselect"></select>`

Comment: `<select id="myselect"></select>`. remove `#` from `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the object and use properties to get the values to appear in the html. Ie: `value.name`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'myurlhere',
        method: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) { 
            $.each(result, function(i, value) {
                 // Access name with value.name etc.      
                 $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.name).attr('value', value.name));
            });
        }
});
```

Also as @Alex Kudryashev pointed out, your select element should be:

```
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

Comment: OK, it's still not appending the data into the select...but I added this: console.log(value.name); inside the loop and it's showing in the console so this means that the only part that's not working is the appending